# ReactJS Accordion - Opening All Accordions When It Should Open One At A Time

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have built an accordion but the state opens each one at a time but I only want one open at a time. I have state working but it is just targeting all of the accordions rather than the actual one. Basically, when a user clicks an accordion, it will drop down and show content, the usual stuff but it is showing all the accordions opening but it should just be one at a time.

Where am I going wrong here:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Icon from '../Icon/Icon';

class RestInfo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      disruptions: [],
      activeAcc: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://trasnport-api-isruptions-v2.azure-api.net/Disruption/v2/', {
        headers: {
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '55060e2bfbf743c5829b9eef583506f7'
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          disruptions: response.data.disruptions
        });
      });
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        activeAcc: !prevState.activeAcc
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { disruptions, activeAcc } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {disruptions.length > 0 ? (
          disruptions.map(post => {
            return (
              <div key={post.id}>
                <div className={`wmnds-accordion ${activeAcc ? 'wmnds-is--open' : ''}`}>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    aria-controls="accordion-custom-01"
                    className="wmnds-accordion__summary-wrapper"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    onClick={this.toggle}
                  >
                    <div className="wmnds-accordion__summary">
                      <div className="wmnds-grid wmnds-grid--align-center">
                        <span className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small wmnds-col-auto wmnds-m-r-md">
                          <svg className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small__icon">
                            <Icon iconName="modes-isolated-bus" iconClass="modes-isolated-bus" />
                          </svg>
                          <svg className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small__icon">
                            <Icon iconName="general-warning-circle" iconClass="general-warning-circle" />
                          </svg>
                        </span>
                        <div className="wmnds-col-auto">
                          <strong>{post.title}</strong>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <svg className="wmnds-accordion__icon">
                      <Icon iconName="general-expand" iconClass="general-expand" />
                    </svg>

                    <svg className="wmnds-accordion__icon wmnds-accordion__icon--minimise">
                      <Icon iconName="general-minimise" iconClass="general-minimise" />
                    </svg>
                  </button>

                  <div className="wmnds-accordion__content" id="accordion-custom-01">
                    <h4 className="serviceAffected">Affected Service(s) </h4>
                    {post.servicesAffected.map(affected => (
                      <div key={affected.id}>
                        <span className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small wmnds-col-auto wmnds-m-r-md">
                          <svg className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small__icon">
                            <Icon iconName="modes-isolated-bus" iconClass="modes-isolated-bus">
                              {affected.serviceNumber}
                            </Icon>
                          </svg>
                          <svg className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small__icon">
                            <Icon iconName="general-warning-circle" iconClass="general-warning-circle" />
                          </svg>
                        </span>

                        <h5>routeDesc:</h5>
                        {affected.routeDesc}
                        <h5>serviceNumber:</h5>
                        {affected.serviceNumber}
                        <h5>direction</h5>
                        {affected.direction}
                      </div>
                    ))}

                    <p>{post.title}</p>
                    <p>{post.description}</p>
                    <p>{post.disruptionSeverity}</p>
                    <p>{post.mode}</p>
                    <p>{post.disruptionSeverity}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div className="wmnds-loader" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RestInfo;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all accordions have the same status, which is why all open and close at the same time. 
  The idea here is to play with the identifier of each Item(accordion). We know all the items in a loop have an identifier starting with zero.
  The opening of the item will be based on the fact that its identifier is equal to activeAcc and the toggle function 
   take this identifier as a parameter in order to be able to assign activeAcc the identifier of the corresponding item.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Icon from '../Icon/Icon';

class RestInfo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      disruptions: [],
      activeAcc: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://trasnport-api-isruptions-v2.azure-api.net/Disruption/v2/', {
        headers: {
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '55060e2bfbf743c5829b9eef583506f7'
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          disruptions: response.data.disruptions
        });
      });
  }

  toggle(key) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        activeAcc: prevState.activeAcc===key?false:key
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { disruptions, activeAcc } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {disruptions.length > 0 ? (
          disruptions.map((post,key) => {
            return (
              <div key={post.id}>
                <div className={`wmnds-accordion ${activeAcc===key ? 'wmnds-is--open' : ''}`}>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    aria-controls="accordion-custom-01"
                    className="wmnds-accordion__summary-wrapper"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    onClick={()=>this.toggle(key)}
                  >
                    <div className="wmnds-accordion__summary">
                      <div className="wmnds-grid wmnds-grid--align-center">
                        <span className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small wmnds-col-auto wmnds-m-r-md">
                          <svg className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small__icon">
                            <Icon iconName="modes-isolated-bus" iconClass="modes-isolated-bus" />
                          </svg>
                          <svg className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small__icon">
                            <Icon iconName="general-warning-circle" iconClass="general-warning-circle" />
                          </svg>
                        </span>
                        <div className="wmnds-col-auto">
                          <strong>{post.title}</strong>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <svg className="wmnds-accordion__icon">
                      <Icon iconName="general-expand" iconClass="general-expand" />
                    </svg>

                    <svg className="wmnds-accordion__icon wmnds-accordion__icon--minimise">
                      <Icon iconName="general-minimise" iconClass="general-minimise" />
                    </svg>
                  </button>

                  <div className="wmnds-accordion__content" id="accordion-custom-01">
                    <h4 className="serviceAffected">Affected Service(s) </h4>
                    {post.servicesAffected.map(affected => (
                      <div key={affected.id}>
                        <span className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small wmnds-col-auto wmnds-m-r-md">
                          <svg className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small__icon">
                            <Icon iconName="modes-isolated-bus" iconClass="modes-isolated-bus">
                              {affected.serviceNumber}
                            </Icon>
                          </svg>
                          <svg className="wmnds-disruption-indicator-small__icon">
                            <Icon iconName="general-warning-circle" iconClass="general-warning-circle" />
                          </svg>
                        </span>

                        <h5>routeDesc:</h5>
                        {affected.routeDesc}
                        <h5>serviceNumber:</h5>
                        {affected.serviceNumber}
                        <h5>direction</h5>
                        {affected.direction}
                      </div>
                    ))}

                    <p>{post.title}</p>
                    <p>{post.description}</p>
                    <p>{post.disruptionSeverity}</p>
                    <p>{post.mode}</p>
                    <p>{post.disruptionSeverity}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div className="wmnds-loader" />
          </div>           )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RestInfo;
```

Comment: Thank you again for this, it was really helpful!

Comment: I just need to make state for  aria-expanded="true"

Comment: it needs to be tue when open and false when closed can you help with this? Please!

Comment: Yes I can do but see the question above please :)

Comment: Okay, let me see!

Comment: Here true is activeAcc===key and false activeAcc!==key

Answer (score 0):

```
class RestInfo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      disruptions: [],
      /** initially all toggles are in false state [false, false, ...] */
      activeAccordions: disruptions.map(i => false) /** [false, false, ..... till disruptions.length] */
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://trasnport-api-isruptions-v2.azure-api.net/Disruption/v2/', {
        headers: {
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '55060e2bfbf743c5829b9eef583506f7'
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          disruptions: response.data.disruptions
        });
      });
  }

  toggle(accordionIndex) {
    let activeAccordions = this.state.disruptions.map(i => false) /** close all open accordions */
    activeAccordions[accordionIndex] = !activeAccordions[accordionIndex] /** toggle the intended accordion */
    this.setState({ activeAccordions: activeAccordions });
  }

  render() {
    const { disruptions, activeAccordions } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        {disruptions.length > 0 ? (
          disruptions.map((post, postIndex) => {
            return (
              <div key={post.id}>
                <div className={`wmnds-accordion ${activeAccordions[postIndex] ? 'wmnds-is--open' : ''}`}>
```